# Highcharts: How can I associate a pre-formatted value with a data point?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For instance, if I have a dynamic chart that has values that might be formatted in several ways for tooltip, can I pass a pre-formatted value along with the raw numeric value somehow?

For instance, a sales Pie chart series value can be:
["Store 1", 3665.54] and the tooltip could be formatted to show $3,665.54,

```
pointFormat: '{series:name}: <b>${point.total}</b>'
```

but a quantity would require different formatting (no Dollar sign).

```
pointFormat: '{series:name}: <b>{point.total}</b>'
```

or it could use a Formatter function, but what if I already have the value as a String ready for display?  How can I associate a pre-formatted value with a data point?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the [`valuePrefix`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.valuePrefix) in the series you need the specific prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Set `pointFormat` for each series: http://jsfiddle.net/g4gqs/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'dogs',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>2 x {point.y}</b><br/>'
        },
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        name: 'cats',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>4 x {point.y}</b><br/>'
        },
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
    }]
```